# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure exception

Tags: java, sslhandshakeexception

I am getting an SSLHandshakeException and have tried the following to fix it with no result:

1. Downloaded the certificate from firefox and generated the keystore using keytool command
2. Added that keystore to the JVM
3. Tried using WireShark

My server has an SSL certificate properly installed. Could there be an issue with the keystore?

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$getResponseCode.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at Groovy_get_user_sessions.print_https_cert(Groovy_get_user_sessions.groovy:225)
    at Groovy_get_user_sessions.this$4$print_https_cert(Groovy_get_user_sessions.groovy)
    at Groovy_get_user_sessions$this$4$print_https_cert.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at Groovy_get_user_sessions.run(Groovy_get_user_sessions.groovy:146)
```

Comment: Please edit with the code that isn't working

Comment: @sak Did you sort this out. I have the same issue and I think it is to do with inadequate secuirty provider cipher suites bundled with JRE. We need JCESafe

Comment: @sak https://github.com/UprootLabs/gngr/issues/11